# ADD CONSTRAINT failing with EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Trying to add another FK to an existing table via EF Code-First.

Fluent API:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
       .HasRequired(c => c.Area)
       .WithMany(d => d.Relationships)
       .HasForeignKey(u => u.AreaId);
```

Relationship class contains this:

```
    [Required]
    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
```

Area class contains this:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
```

Output from PM Console:

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Relationship] ADD [AreaId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Relationship] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Relationship_dbo.Area_AreaId] FOREIGN KEY ([AreaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Area] ([AreaId])
```

First, what is `Area_AreaId`?

Second, how to I know whether to set the Fluent API on the Relationship entity, or the Area entity, or Both?

The error I get:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Relationship_dbo.Area_AreaId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "db", table "dbo.Area", column 'AreaId'.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a value in `Relationship.AreaId` that does not exist in `Area.AreaId` so the FK constraint cannot be applied.

In the previous statement, you added the `AreaId` column to the `Relationship` table and set a default of `0`.  Any existing rows will have had their `AreaId` set to `0`.  Then you tried to add the foreign key constraint but I bet you have no `Area.AreaId` of `0` to satisfy it.

Perhaps, if areas are optional for relationships, you could make it nullable in the class?

```
public int? AreaId { get; set; }
```

I guess this would cause EF to produce a nullable column instead, hence no default of 0.

Comment: You're right, I don't.  I'm at a loss on how to solve it though... should I set AreaId as nullable, then seed, then re-apply the constraint?

Comment: See my update - but only set AreaId to nullable if it is really allowed to have no value.  Otherwise, update your data first to add valid AreaId values from the Area table, then apply the constraint.

Comment: OK, I'll try that.  Thank you.  RE my use of HasForeignKey - does that look right to you?  I wasn't sure whether to use AreaId or RelationshipId.  In case it matters - A Relationship should always have one Area, and a relationship can be deleted, but an Area cannot, and an Area has many relationships.

Comment: I think it's fine.  As you've now said that a relationship **must** have an area, you should correct your data and then apply the constraint.  Don't use the nullable property in this case, as you always want a value.

Comment: Are you available for ~1 hour of paid "tutoring"?  I'm trying to figure this stuff out and keep running into problems.  My email is mga2048@gmail.com in case you're available.